# multiple select boxes - getting values into an array

Tags: javascript

I have a select box that the options are populated from ajax.
I also have a button that when clicked clones the select box.

```
<select name="subcat[0]" id="subcat">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
<button name="addmore">Add More</button>
```

when I click add more it will clone the subcat and increment it so the name is subcat[1], etc...

I need to be able to capture all the values of each select and put them in a single array. 
my problem is that even if the user changes again his select option it still keeps the last value selected as well.

```
var elem = document.getElementById('subcat')
var points = [];
for(var i=0,len=elem.length;i<len;i++){    
  if (elem[i].selected){    
    points.push(elem[i].value);                 
  }
}
```

how can I remove the last option selected if the user just changed the same select?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the last selected and can splice it from the array, if I recall correctly you can splice if like this (*supposing that `x` has last value*):

```
if(x==elem[i].selected){
    elem[i].splice(i,1);  //cuts one index in the array where x occurs
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var elem = document.getElementById('subcat')
var points = [];
for(var i=0,len=elem.length;i<len;i++){

  if (elem[i].selected){
    if(points[points.length-1] == elem[i].value){
      points.pop();
    }
    points.push(elem[i].value);

  }
}
```

Comment: if i do this than it only compares the last value but that can cause an issue if the value can be in both. i need to check if it was chosen from the same selected list and if it was then to remove it